# Will Ubuntu 13.04 remove Windows?

Tags: windows, uninstall

On Download Menu it says `Download Ubuntu desktop and replace your current operating system whether it’s Windows or Mac OS` or `run Ubuntu alongside it`.

So I was wondering if it means that Ubuntu will remove Windows(Meaning I will not have access to it "anymore") or it won't and it will be used as "Option" choices when powering on PC?

Comment: It will do what you want it too. The installer gives you the choice to either take over the entire machine or install side by side.  If you want to install with Windows 8 see [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed Windows 8 (64-bit) System](http://askubuntu.com/q/221835/107450) otherwise see [How do I install Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/q/6328/107450)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cool thing with the ubuntu installer is **this** (Btw, this is from 12.04, but it's the same concept)

-

[image: Installation from 12.04]

When you install Ubuntu, you can choose to use it apart from Windows (or other operating systems) when you start your computer, and it won't be removed.

Please note that the picture above describes the situation when Windows 7 is installed. This screen may change depending on which OS and system (partitions and harddrives) you've got.

You will still be able to browse files on your old OS's (such as pictures and documents) while using Ubuntu installed alongside with other operating systems.

Comment: Do mind that this installation type screen will be -different- based on the setup the installer encounters. If you have windows xp and 7 and 8 on the machine you get more options. If you have unallocated space you get an option to install into that part etc etc.

Comment: @Rinzwind Of course, i am aware of that; BUT it's still \possible\ to install alongside, if you got enough space on your hardrive. The partitions can be modified and customized afterwards.

Comment: Oh that was more of a general comment for anyone expecting to see those exact screen ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could always us virtual box, but then you don't ACTUALLY have ubuntu downloaded, you'll have a virtual hard drive for it. It's easy though.

Comment: Sounds like a smart solution too, smart thought!

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu can dual-boot alongside any already existing operating system, meaning that it wont replace the current system,. but rather runs alongside it...

Also, you can access files from your other operating system whilst running ubuntu

Comment: Are you repeating the answer here 48 minutes after it got posted, or? Anyways, great that you mentioned that you can access files and documents from other OS's when running ubuntu. I forgot that.